# Internet connection in android wear watch?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Can you share the ways the android wear watch can connect to internet while it is not pared with mobile device.( Eg: is it possible to connect via wifi, or data connection).

Comment: it can't. Connection goes trough the handheld devices. The information are exchanged through bluetooth

Comment: Not yet. Rumors say that Wi-Fi support will be added in the next release of Android Wear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot and there are no Android Wear devices supporting Wi-Fi, at this time (On March 2015).

**Update:** Some devices (not all) should see Wi-Fi support incoming according to http://googleblog.blogspot.fr/2015/04/android-wear-wear-what-you-want-get.html

Comment: Is this still relevant now that new versions of Android Wear enabled wi-fi support on some watches (eg, Galaxy Gear)? I'm wondering if I can create an app for wear that can connect to the internet while the phone is not around